Combine DTM with hillshade in QGIS
I'm wondering if it is possible to combine a LiDAR generated DTM on a 1m Scale with a Hillshade DTM on a 0,25m Scale to improve the level of detail of the LiDAR DTM.
If possible how can this be done in QGIS?
Here are two samples:
1m LiDAR DTM

0,25m Hillshade DTM


Not really, as a hillshade is not a DTM (it contains no elevation values). You can overlay them (put hillshade on top and set opacity to 50%) or you can display the lidar DTM as a hillshade (QGIS layer properties, symbology, render type = hillshade). You could also have the lidar DTM in the map twice, first with hillshade symbology and 50% opacity and 2nd as elevation with a nice elevation colour ramp.

You can overlay the rasters with the DEM on top with blending mode Multiply to get this effect
